# Xamarin android: FirebaseInstanceIdService was deprecated but no OnNewToken in FirebaseMessagingService

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase for push notification on Xamarin form for android.

I have installed Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging package and knowing that the FirebaseInstanceIdService is going to be deprecated. I am extends the FirebaseMessagingService and want to override the OnNewToken function.

Some how i can find the OnNewToken to override.

Currently package i have installed was Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging 60.1142.1 from nuget.

Comment: Known issue with the Xamarin bindings in 60.x (and 71.x preview) releases: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents/issues/197

Comment: Sorry what should i do. Do i stick with the old way and will that still working for future release

Comment: Yep, use the old Firebase Service until Xamarin publishes a corrected version or build your own bindings using the latest Google libraries and Xamarin's repo code (this is what I do since Xamarin skips some Google releases|versions and|or their release schedule is too slow , this issue was changed from high to low priority...I would *assume* missing API members to be high, but that is just me.... thus why I build my own)

Answer (score 6):

Today, the most current version is 121.0.1, if you can update Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging the method looks like this:

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
{
    const string TAG = "Firebase";

    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "Update Token: " + token);

        Preferences.Set("TokenFirebase", token);
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: For Android 12 and above, you need [Service(Exported = true)]